# Can Ghosts hold on to their Intellectual property?

Tags: supernatural, ghost

In the TV series *Supernatural*, and many other movies/stories we see that ghosts stay on Earth because of some item of theirs instead of going to Heaven/Hell. And burning/destroying that item is the way to put them to rest.

I was wondering whether a ghost can hold on to some intellectual property that they made during their life? If yes, then how can one put such a ghost to rest? If no, why not?

Comment: By getting congress to not extend the copyright laws and let it go to the public domain, of course.

Comment: @fire.eagle clearly ghosts are already influencing congress, as copyright now stays for about 70-120 years after the creators death. Stop the ghost lobby!

Comment: Eh, are you asking if ghosts can anchor themselves to their intellectual property? If so, I don't think so as ghosts anchor themselves to some physical, iirc.